# Mass-Energy equivalence - speed of light?

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light, mass-energy

According to Einstein, $E=mc^2$.
Is $c$ always the speed of light in vacuum in this equation?

And for the relativistic mass: $m=\frac{m_0}{\sqrt{1-(v/c)^2}}$ does the same hold for $c$ here?

So if I have an object of 1kg of mass resting under water. Its energy is simply $E=mc^2$?

And how is the energy stored? In what forms is it in for example a resting solid body?

Comment: Please ask only one question at a time (and relativistic mass has been abandoned for a long time now, so you can just drop that one entirely)

Answer (score 1):

When c is seen in a physics article , it is only the speed of light in vacuum that is referred.

The relativistic mass  concept, as Dale said in the comments, has been abandoned, since in order to avoid confusion the special relativity algebra with [its four vectors](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Relativ/vec4.html) is used in order to describe energy and momentum, at the relativistic velocities that the formula of relativistic mass has any measurable value.

The relativistic mass is useful if one wants to calculate how much more fuel will be needed to push a spaceship from a given relativistic velocity to a bigger one. It is the m one should put for relativistic velocities in the classical mechanics F=ma, the classical inertial mass, and the concept is confusing and not used in particle physics any longer.

The invariant mass, $m_0$ is  the "length"  of the four vector, it characterizes a particle  uniquely.

[image: invar mass]

The mass of any composite of particles object, invariant under Lorentz transformations, is given by the same formula ,where the four vector of the object  is the sum of the four vectors of the individual particles.

> So if i have an object of 1kg of mass resting under water. Its energy is simply E=m*c^2 ?

If it is resting, the m is the invariant mass as described above, it is the case where the outdated "relativistic mass" concept is identical (within possible experimental errors in mass measurement) with the rest mass. In any case , the invariant mass,  ( length of summed four vector) , is the mass to use for the object.

Comment: Unless the stationary 1kg object is also at absolute zero, its inertial mass and rest mass differ by $U/c^2$.

Comment: @gs which is within experimental errors of mass measurement. I will edit.

Answer (score 0):

In your equations, c is indeed the speed of light, 3 x 10^8 m/s in the vacuum.

Energy in physics is a quantity that is conserved under time evolution.  The definition of rest energy of things having some mass as such $E=mc^2$ was needed with the advent of relativity to account for it being able to be converted to kinetic energy and vice versa.

For example, suppose you have 2 rocks which you collide.  At low energies you could say the energy is just the sum of the newtonian kinetic energy ($\frac{1}{2} m v^2$ for each rock) and for an elastic collision, this sum will be the same.  However if you collide the "rocks" you are colliding are protons at the LHC, one finds that you can literally create new particles by imparting enough energy to your proton.  This happens when the speed of your particle is large $v \rightarrow c$.  Therefore, energy being a concept that just has newtonian kinetic energy is no longer a valid experimental fact and had to be modified.  The modified formula is below:

$$ E = \sqrt{m^2c^4 + (pc)^2}$$

This is the quantity that is conserved in the universe in general.  At rest it reproduces $E=mc^2$ as expected.

Comment: Your second paragraph (second sentence) seems to be saying that rest energy is conserved. You don't mean this, do you?

Comment: well any type of energy is conserved? it just transforms into different forms or not?

Comment: sorry I didn't mean that.  Will correct.

Answer (score 0):

References to the "speed of light" or $c$ in relativity are always about the "speed of light in vacuum" (except for very very rare circumstances that are explicitly spelled out). So yes, in $E = mc^2$ the $c$ is always the speed of light in vacuum, even if you're in an environment (such as underwater) where the local speed of light is less.

$c$ is known as the "speed of light (in vacuum)" for historical reasons, but that's probably a bad name, because it misleads people into thinking about the light, rather than the speed. Better names would be "speed of causality", or "invariant speed", or even "speed of gravity".

The important thing is that in our universe there is a particular speed $c$ that serves as a scaling factor for converting space to time. All massless particles (including photons, which make up light) travel at this speed in vacuum, and all observers agree on this speed.